# python signal handler react slow when heavy loading

Tags: python, signals

I wrote a signal handler that can restart the script it self by:

```
kill -10 $PID
```

and I register the handler in the beginning of the script.

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, restart_handler)
```

My script mainly do below things:

- download some source code.
- unzip it and other stuff.
- use os.system(bash -c 'make -j16 > log.txt')

When downloading source code, I use `kill -10` to restart it, 
it runs the handler quickly and normally as I expected.

However, when it start to `make -j16`, I use the same kill command,
but need to wait very long time to reach signal handler.
(looks like the signal is not handled immediately,
 but if I use `kill -9 $PID` it can be killed immediately)

How to make my customized signal handler can act as quick as `-9`?

below picture it the pstree output when `make -j16`:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rbfzn0p0f2p55xx/make.png

Comment: I am trying to replace os.system with subprocess.call and check again later.

Comment: after using subprocess.call, it work quickly and normally...although I don't understand why fork and exec make signal handling so different...